# com.maverick.ssh.SshException: Key exchange failed: Expected SSH_MSG_KEX_GEX_GROUP [id=3]

Tags: java, ssh

Environment

1. Java 1.7.0_79
2. SFTP client
   OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
3. SFTP server
   SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.10

Action:
SFTP client try to connect to SFTP server using java. As result, it has error:

```
Caused by: com.maverick.ssh.SshException: Key exchange failed: Expected SSH_MSG_KEX_GEX_GROUP [id=3] [Unknown cause]
    at com.maverick.ssh.components.jce.DiffieHellmanGroupExchangeSha1.performClientExchange(Unknown Source)
    at com.maverick.ssh2.TransportProtocol.e(Unknown Source)
    at com.maverick.ssh2.TransportProtocol.processMessage(Unknown Source)
    at com.maverick.ssh2.TransportProtocol.startTransportProtocol(Unknown Source)
    at com.maverick.ssh2.Ssh2Client.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.maverick.ssh.SshConnector.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.maverick.ssh.SshConnector.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.bea.wli.sb.transports.sftp.client.SFTPClient.authenticate(SFTPClient.java:236)
    at com.bea.wli.sb.transports.sftp.connector.SFTPResource.<init>(SFTPResource.java:89)
    at com.bea.wli.sb.transports.sftp.resource.SFTPUtils.createSFTPResource(SFTPUtils.java:153)
    at com.bea.wli.sb.transports.sftp.connector.SFTPWorkPartitioningAgent.getSftpResource(SFTPWorkPartitioningAgent.java:161)
    ... 9 more
```

This error is generated by the DiffieHellmanGroupExchangeSha1 class from j2ssh-maverick:
https://github.com/sshtools/j2ssh-maverick/blob/master/j2ssh-maverick/src/main/java/com/sshtools/ssh/components/jce/DiffieHellmanGroupExchangeSha1.java

```
final static int SSH_MSG_KEXDH_GEX_GROUP = 31;
...
byte[] tmp = transport.nextMessage();
...
if (tmp[0] != SSH_MSG_KEXDH_GEX_GROUP) {
transport.disconnect(TransportProtocol.KEY_EXCHANGE_FAILED,
"Expected SSH_MSG_KEX_GEX_GROUP");
throw new SshException(
"Key exchange failed: Expected SSH_MSG_KEX_GEX_GROUP [id="
+ tmp[0] + "]", SshException.INTERNAL_ERROR);
}
```

because of this code, get the description of the error:

```
Key exchange failed: Expected SSH_MSG_KEX_GEX_GROUP [id=3]
```

It means after request SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST expecting response with value «31» to continue connecting.

Experiment conducted:

1. If to connect from cleint with OpenSSH_7.2p2 to server with OpenSSH_5.3p1, it has ssh log behind:

```
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(2048<3072<8192) sent
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: bits set: 1511/3072
debug3: send packet: type 32
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 33
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
```

2. If to connect from cleint with OpenSSH_5.3p1 to server with OpenSSH_5.3p1 or OpenSSH_7.2p2, it has ssh log behind:

```
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<2048<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug3: Wrote 24 bytes for a total of 909
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 162/320
debug2: bits set: 1044/2048
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
```

For the first experiment it get value «31», but for the second experiment no any information about value «3» ([id=3]).

Why is different log stack between two experiments?
How to solve this error?